# Relative $G$-equivariant homology groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, equivariant-homotopy, transformation-groups

Let $X$ be a free $G$-CW-complex with $G$-equivariant cell filtration by
$n$-skeleta $X_0 \subset \dots \subset X_n \subset \dots \subset X$ (for
rigorous definition see
Chap. II, p. 98 in linked source below).

Question: Why holds

$$   H_n(X_n, X_{n-1}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}G} \mathbb{Z} \cong
H_n(X_n/G, X_{n-1}/G) $$

for the relative homology groups (which by construction carry $\mathbb{Z}G$-module structure)? Clearly, the relative complexes
$C_*(X_n, X_{n-1})$ are free $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules more less by assumption on freeness of $G$ action &
compatibility of cell filtration with $G$.
But does this hold for homology groups too? (here I have the universal coefficient theorem in mind)

If the relative homology group is not $\mathbb{Z}G$-free, why should else the isomorphism above be true?

Source: This was stated without a proof in Proposition 9.7. (ii) (page 165)
in [Transformation Groups](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110858372/html) by Tammo tom Dieck.
This suggests that at all this should follow as a "triviality" but honestly I not see
an immediate reason for this.

Comment: The differential on $C_*(X_n,X_{n-1})$ is zero, since everything is concentrated in dimension $n$. Thus you can freely replace $H_n$ by $C_n$.

Comment: Henrik's comment looks like an answer to me.

Comment: Ok I post it as an answer, so that the question is closable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differential on $C_*(X_n,X_{n−1})$ is zero, since everything is concentrated in dimension $n$. Thus you can freely replace $H_n$ by $C_n$.